# In Unity, Implementing and overriding network manager for creating custom network manager

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I need some answers for developing server for unity. In unity how can I implement network manager to create my network manager for connecting remote server? I'm gonna develop java socket server for my game but I could not find anything about communication with remote server. It just only about local server and clients. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Pretty broad topic.  I will say, UNET's networkmanager is not, as you say, "only about local server and clients."

Comment: hi are you talking about internet based networking?